# Add an order value to zend form fieldset items

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a product entity with an image collection.
Now I want to give an order to the images.

I want to do this by drag and drop the image order in the form. Every image has his own name like name="product['images][][url].

In just plain php i could loop trough te post after submitting and set the index value to an order field. But how can i do this with a Zend form that is hydrated by doctrine?

Image entity

```
<?php
/**
 * BjyAuthorize Module (https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize)
 *
 * @link https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize for the canonical source repository
 * @license http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace ApplicationShared\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * An example entity that represents a image.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 *
 * @author Tom Oram <tom@scl.co.uk>
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="url", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=false, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $order;  

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApplicationShared\Entity\Product", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $product;


    /**
     * Get the id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the id.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int)$id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the url.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

     /**
     * Set the store id.
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = (string) $url;
    }

    /**
     * Allow null to remove association
     *
     * @param Product $product
     */
    public function setProduct(Product $product = null)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * Get product.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Get the order.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Set the order.
     *
     * @param int $order
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setOrder($order)
    {
        $this->order = (int) $order;
    }

}
```

product entity

```
<?php
namespace ApplicationShared\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApplicationShared\Entity\ProductInterface;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ApplicationShared\Repositories\ProductRepository")
 *
 */
class Product implements ProductInterface
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ApplicationShared\Entity\Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"},orphanRemoval=true)
     * )
     */
    protected $images;

    /**
     * Initialies the roles variable.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Get images.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * Add a image to the product.
     *
     * @param Images
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function addImages(Collection $images)
    {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $image->setProduct($this);
            $this->images->add($image);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection $images
     */
    public function removeImages(Collection $images)
    {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $image->setProduct(null);
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
        }
    }
}
```

My product form

```
<?php

namespace Backend\Form;

use ApplicationShared\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;


 class ProductFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
 {
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager, $userid, $storeid)
    {
         parent::__construct('product');

         $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new Product());



        $imagesFieldset = new ImageFieldset($objectManager);
        $this->add(array(
             'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
                'name' => 'images',
                'options' => array(
                    'count' => 0,
                    'target_element' => $imagesFieldset
                )

         ));

     }
 }
```

Image fieldset

```
namespace Backend\Form;

use ApplicationShared\Entity\Image;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;


 class ImageFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
 {
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
         parent::__construct('image');

         $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new Image());

         $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
            'name' => 'id',
            'attributes' => array(
                'class'=>'imageId'
            )
        ));

         $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
            'name' => 'order'
        ));

         $this->add(array(
             'name' => 'url',
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'required' => 'required'
                )
         ));
     }

     /**
      * @return array
      */
     public function getInputFilterSpecification()
     {
         return array(
             'id' => array(
                'required' => false
            ),
             'url' => array(
                 'required' => true,
             ),
         );
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@OrderBy` annotation ([documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby)) in images relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ApplicationShared\Entity\Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"order" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $images;
```

Image collection is then always ordered by this specification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid I was not clear enough. I improved my question. Your solution is good for retrieving data from the database, but I need to save an order value to the database.